# Unknown error occurring when compiling in eclipse

Tags: java, swing

```
public class code extends JFrame{
   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   public boolean flag = true;
   JButton Bill;
   JButton Enter;
   JTextField Items;
   JTextField Amount;
   public java.util.List<String> Item_list = new ArrayList<String>();
   public java.util.List<String> quantity = new ArrayList<String>();

   public code() {
      super("Market");

      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      do {
         Items = new JTextField("Enter the Item u wish to purchase");
         add(Items);
         Items.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    command(e.getActionCommand());
                }
            }
         );

         Amount = new JTextField("Enter the quantity of the product");
         add(Amount);
         Amount.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    commandInt(e.getActionCommand());
                }
            }
         );
         Bill = new JButton();
         add(Bill);
         Bill.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
         );

      } while(flag);
   }    

   public void command(String userT) {
      try {
         Item_list.add(userT);
      } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("what was that");
      }
   }

   public void commandInt(String string) {
      try {
        quantity.add(string);
      } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("what was that");
      }
   }
}
```

This code is basically just a system where u input the item and the amount and it stores it in a list but something is obviously wrong because it doesn't compile. Further when it does compile they highlighted region `JTextField` area. there seems to be no apparent problem.

Comment: Have you made the necessary imports?

Comment: I checked in my eclipse but there is no issue related to compilation , can you recheck the import.

Comment: You know you can find out what the error/warning is by just placing your mouse over the error. For those who are too lazy to copy and paste your code (which would cause many errors out the gate for the lack of imports) it would be nice to know what the error is

Comment: Maybe the compiler just doesn't like your disregard for Java naming convention :) (Class names being with upper case letters and variables begin with lower case - you have it reversed)

Comment: Also you say "something is wrong because the code doesn't compile". Then you say "when it does compile...". So is this question about a compile error or a warning. unclear what your asking

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't specify the error or warning I'll give a general answer.

If you hover over the words that are underlined then they will give you a brief description of the problem.

In eclipse you can use the shortcut alt + enter to get suggestions on how to solve the problem.

If the problem is an error then it will be highlighted red. Else, if it is a warning then it will be underlined yellow.

An error is a fault in the code you wrote where a warning is more of a suggestion from a good friend telling you to fix something.

Comment: as i said it just highlights the  "Items = new JTextField("Enter the Item u wish to purchase");" an the " Amount = new JTextField("Enter the quantity of the product");" lines with out specifing the error.     Further the errors in the console shows like 20 lines of "source unknown".

Comment: @user3901683 Does it say something when you do alt enter when you have your selector where that problem is? Do any of the source unknown errors share the same line number as this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the classes you are using:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
```